Excel Scripts to delete row based on value
Really hoping someone can point me in the right direction, due to moving to office online I am trying to replace old macros in a worksheet with scripts and have become stuck as completely new to this.
I am trying to run a script that in each sheet would delete a row if the value in column CA = 0, is this possible?
Tried writing scripts

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {

  let worksheets = workbook.getWorksheets();
  worksheets.forEach(worksheet => {
    let usedRange = worksheet.getUsedRange();
    // CA is 79th column
    let columnCA = usedRange.getColumn(79).getValues();

    for (let i = columnCA.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      // Check if the value in column CA is 0
      if (columnCA[i][0] === 0) {
        // Delete the row if the value is 0
        worksheet.getRange(`A${i + 1}`).getEntireRow().delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
      }
    }
  });
}

First it fetches all the worksheets and then determines the range of each worksheet that has been used. The it checks the value of the CA of each row. If its 0 then it deletes the row.(I am assuming this is what you asked for)
To run the script Go to Automate > New Script.

huge thank you for your help, im getting the following error:
Line 7: Range getColumn: Parameter out of range
any chance you know how to tweak?

Its Most likely due to 79 number column is out of used range . The value should be the value of number of the column CA
